# Func<...> args have "unnamed" parameters. Is there a way to name them?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, func

Is there a way to named parameters of a generic Func<...> to have support of intellisense?

Example:

```
Func<int, int, int> f1 = new Func<int, int, int>(
    (a, b) => { return a + b }
);

f1(2, 3);
```

[image]

Comment: Depends - are you using `Func<>` because you need a `Func<>` or because of its convenience? If you need a `Func<>` it's already been defined and has the names it has.

Comment: Why not create your own delegate that has the parameter names you desire?

Answer (score 5):

No. You can define your own delegate/interface, though.

```cs
public delegate int DoTheThing(int a, int b);
```

or

```cs
public interface IThingDoer {
    int DoTheThing(int a, int b);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this with `Func<...>` since it is already has names for the type parameters (it's just a normal generic type).

You could define a delegate instead (which has to be defined at class level - you can't define it within a method or as a method parameter):

```
public delegate int MyFunc(int a, int b);
```

Then you just use it like:

```
public static int MyMethod(MyFunc myfunc)
{
    return myfunc(1, 2);
}

public static int MyOtherMethod()
{
    return MyMethod((a, b) => a + b);
}
```

One somewhat grungy workaround could be to use a tuple for the arguments:

```
public static int MyMethod(Func<(int a, int b), int> myFunc)
{
    return myFunc((1, 2));
}

public static int MyOtherMethod()
{
    return MyMethod(tuple => tuple.a + tuple.b);
}
```

Then intellisense will tell you the names of the tuple members. I wouldn't do this though - I'm just mentioning it for completeness.